# Consumable In-App Purchase not available during app review process

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, revenuecat

My App was rejected because of error during payment process. The reason of an error was an empty product list returned via store kit API.

I’ve added Consumable In-App purchase with all required details. In-App Purchase is currently in `Waiting for Review` state and `Cleared for sales` is selected. Everything is working fine when I'm testing this via `TestFlight` using `Sandbox` mode.

Should I wait till In-App Purchase will be in `Ready to submit` state, before I will submit first version of my app for review?

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Finally my build was approved.

I've noticed that in-app product after the 3rd review changed to `Developer Action Needed` with marked Localizations sections.

In my opinion everything was fine with it so I've just added new English (US) version (not required for that product).

[image]

Before I've submit a new build I've change one more thing in the code:

```
- Purchases.setDebugLogsEnabled(true);
+ Purchases.setDebugLogsEnabled(false);
```

Not sure if any of those changes had an impact but anyway build has been approved